# Logging Error Details once .Net application is Deployed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, error-logging

I recently deployed my .Net MVC application on the server. Now, users are complaining me about the bugs which they are facing while working with the application.

How can I log the details of the bugs which users are facing so I can understand and fix them as soon as possible. Someone suggested me to write code in `global.asax` file that will log bugs in the database. On the internet, people are suggesting to use **ELMAH** to log error details.

What are the possible solutions to log the error details? Which one is best and most recommended?

Answer (score 0):

There are obviously many options to logging errors. One I found to be best for my team is that when an error is logged, it is also **emailed** to us. Of course, too many emails and you end up ignoring them so we're cautious to send only emails from a certain level up.